# Evaluate statement in IF condition in Excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to set up a budget where my last column shows what's left in my account in every cell from `F6` to `F30`. I want the cell to only show it's value if another cell on the same row has a value.

#### Example:

If `B6` is not empty, show the value of cell `F6`, leaving the rest of the cells in `column F` blank until they are summed up.The value in `F6` is a formula from a different spreadsheet (`=DATA!AH6`).

I have tried `=IF(B6="";"";"=DATA!AH6")`, but it shows the text 'DATA!AH6', and not the value.

Comment: Uhh @Tia, you might want to vote up and accept my answer if you feel it was helpful or it worked

Comment: Thank you. Can't get it to work in my sheet, but trying ; instead of , and with and without quotatinmarks.

Comment: Are you sure about using semicolons? I've only seen commas till now.

Comment: I'm using an european version of 2007, and not really able to find my way around it as I'm used to an english version of 2010.

Comment: Btw, how do I vote/accept?

Comment: See screenshot: http://imgur.com/B244z

Comment: See screenshot: http://imgur.com/HfL8E

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Answer accepted, but can't vote unless I'm registered. Sorry.

Comment: It's fine. Glad to help. (BTW, why not register)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `=DATA!AH6` w/o the quotes. Your formula should now look like

```
=IF(B6="","",=DATA!AH6)
```

This worked for me:

```
   A   B   ...
1 100 200
2  1  =IF(A2="1",SUM(A1:B1),"")
...
```